# Python Filing - need help (beginner stuff)

Tags: python, file

I've recently started learning about python filing so i'm not that great unfortunately which is why I need your help with this basic file program i'm trying to create.
Basically, i'm entering first name, surname, age, score in this format:
e.g:

```
John    Smith    17    22 (the spaces are tabs)
Tom     Jones    34    18
Lewis   Martins  23    20
```

So far i've created this, which works but only gets the first score, but I need to get all of them:

```
    F = open('Program File','r')

    score_string = ''
    count = 0

    while count < 3:
        readit = F.read(1)
        if readit == '\t':
            count += 1
    score_string += F.readline()
    print(score_string)
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `csv` module.

Comment: @Wooble no idea what the csv module is or how to use it, as I said i'm a beginner at files.. :o

Comment: You can find the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in your loop you pass only three tabs in first line. You need to continue reading to read all the lines.

But you could do that in more pythonic (and simpler) way:

```
with open('Program File', 'r') as f: # open file
    for line in f: # get each line
        row = line.split('\t') # split line into in list by tabs
        print row[3] # print fourth value
```

Comment: Works, and much more smaller.. thanks! btw, is there any specific reason why you used "with open(...) as f" ? or is it just for making it smaller?

Comment: @user2993584 Yes, there is specific reason. "with" will automatically close file in the end of block and even in case of exception. See: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are reading only one line. Use a while loop over lines in the file:

```
with open('Program File','r') as F:
    for line in F:
        name, surname, age, score=line.split('\t')
        print(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to parse the file at the same time as reading it, read each line first and split on tabs:

```
with open('Program File') as f:
    for line in f:
        first_name, surname, age, score = line.strip().split('\t')
        print score
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
     data = [l.strip().split('\t') for l in f]
```

This will give something like:

```
data == [["John", "Smith", "17", "22"], ...]
```

You can then process the `data` to turn the last value into an integer:

```
scores = [int(l[3]) for l in data]
```

Comment: He didn't hardcode the number of records. That `while` loop skips to the fourth column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and a dictionary:

```
import csv

data={}
with open('/tmp/test.tsv') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        data[(line[1], line[0])]=line[2:]

print(data) 
# {('Jones', 'Tom'): ['34', '18'], ('Smith', 'John'): ['17', '22'], ('Martins', 'Lewis'): ['23', '20']}
```

Since this is a dictionary of lists, to access Tom Jones' age you would do `data[('Jones', 'Tom')][0]`

Or, if you want named values so that you can access your data like this:

```
data[('Martins', 'Lewis')]['score']
```

you could use a nested dict of dicts:

```
data={}
with open('/tmp/test.tsv') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        data[(line[1], line[0])]={'age':line[2], 'score':line[3]} 

# data={('Martins', 'Lewis'): {'age': '23', 'score': '20'}, ('Smith', 'John'): {'age': '17', 'score': '22'}, ('Jones', 'Tom'): {'age': '34', 'score': '18'}}
```